# VB6で「vbCrLf」で改行した際の1行空きを詰めて削除したい

Tags: vb6

VB6で③のコードを実行すると①の出力結果が得られる状況です。
これを②のように行を詰めて空きを削除したいです。

ご知見を頂けますと有難く存じます。

①出力ファイル「out.txt」

```
  1   1  0.000E+00  0.000E+00  0.000E+00   2  1.634E-06 -4.240E-06 -2.448E-05   3  ･･･

  2   1  0.000E+00  0.000E+00  0.000E+00   2  3.268E-06 -8.480E-06 -4.897E-05   3  ･･･

  3   1  0.000E+00  0.000E+00  0.000E+00   2  4.902E-06 -1.272E-05 -7.345E-05   3  ･･･
```

②要望の出力ファイル「out.txt」

```
  1   1  0.000E+00  0.000E+00  0.000E+00   2  1.634E-06 -4.240E-06 -2.448E-05   3  ･･･
  2   1  0.000E+00  0.000E+00  0.000E+00   2  3.268E-06 -8.480E-06 -4.897E-05   3  ･･･
  3   1  0.000E+00  0.000E+00  0.000E+00   2  4.902E-06 -1.272E-05 -7.345E-05   3  ･･･
```

③コード

```
Public Sub Output()

    outputFile = "out.txt"

    outputNum = FreeFile
    Open outputFile For Append As outputNum

    Dim step As String, node As String, _
        x As String, y As String, rot As String
        
    RSet step = CStr(Format(Istp, "0"))
    Print #outputNum, step;

    For J = 1 To NODE
        RSet node = CStr(Format(J, "0"))
        RSet x = CStr(Format(D(3 * J - 2, Istp), "0.000E+00")):    RSet y = CStr(Format(D(3 * J - 1, Istp), "0.000E+00"))
        RSet rot = CStr(Format(D(3 * J, Istp), "0.000E+00"))
        Print #outputNum, node; x; y; rot;
    Next J
   
    Print #outputNum, vbCrLf

Close #outputNum

End Sub
```

Comment: `Print #outputNum, vbCrLf`の後ろにも`;`を付けて`Print #outputNum, vbCrLf;`として試してみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: ご指摘のとおり実施したところ成功しました。有難うございます。